# Suggestions for javascript/typescript library which provides common abstraction to multiple databases

Tags: javascript, typescript, database-connection

We are working on a product which to support writing data to multiple database types (postgrs, oracle, mysql and mssql). We want to use a javascript/typescript library which facilitates interacting with these dbs with common abstraction.

We cannot use orms (like typeorm) because the schema is not know at compile time and it is something configured by clients.

Do you know of any library which provides abstracted db access which supports above mentioned dbs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found that [Knex](http://knexjs.org/) is great db abstraction library which is lower level than ORM and it was exactly the kind of thing we were looking for.